# How to Rewrite 301

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've got to update my site (it's on joomla). 
And i want to rewrite URLs to fit new URLs.

Everything is the same except "/de" in URL

so.. old URL is like this: http://breitenbachmedia.com/index.php/medienanalyse
and new URL is like: http://breitenbachmedia.com/index.php/de/medienanalysen

so, i wanna rewrite all adresses with one rule just adding /de/ is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mediaanalyse/(.*)$ http://breitenbachmedia.com/index.php/de/medienanalysen/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule as your **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!de/).*)$ /de/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```